# How to debug widget applications in Xamarin studio?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm experimenting with [Simple widget application](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SimpleWidget) in Xamarin studio and would like to know how to debug it. Trying regular 'Run -> Start Debugging' (F5) produces

> Application does not contain a launchable activity

As far as I understand [ActivityAttribute.MainLauncher](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.App.ActivityAttribute.MainLauncher) property is designed specifically for this purpose but there is no activity to apply it to in the example I'm playing with.

p.s.
Is there something similar to 'Attach to process' feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is still no simple solution other than embedding your widget into a self created activity just for the debugging purposes. The last post from the Xamarin team I've found is [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.mono.monodroid/4326).

I've tried a few approaches with an empty activity and trying to trick the debugger - but failed.